# Vscode update imports (AutoImports)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I develop in Typescript on vscode. Sometimes in the codebase when I move a folder or I rename it the `import ... from ...` are not updated in the files.

Is there a vscode extension that get into each `.ts` file and modify the imports so that it takes into account the new path of the file from which the import is made?

Typically I want to run a command in vs code like: F1 +`AutoImports: Update imports`

Comment: if it is not supported by the refactor items implemented by VSC team you can always write one yourself